# What is superior customization and changes you do it in visual studio IDE and other IDE

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Programmer using IDE more than else and mean to him a lot. But some time we need to customize it and change preference.

What is superior customization and changes you do it in visual studio IDE and other IDE?

Answer (score 3):

[Viemu](http://www.viemu.com/), an addin that lets you use vi key bindings in Visual Studio. You'd be surprised how much time this saves!

Answer (score 1):

Most supiror for me is changing apperence for IDE Background and font color and font type

Answer (score 1):

Usually i reorganize toolbars position and i try to get as much space as i can for code window.
[Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is also a must for me since i work a lot with SVN and this plugin works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I love [making strings stand out](http://www.secretgeek.net/IDETips.asp) with a purple background and a white foreground.